# How to rearrange vector to be cols not rows?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, armadillo

I am solving systems of equations using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html). I make a matrix from one array of doubles, specifying the rows and columns. The problem is that it doesn't read it the way I make the array, (it's a vector but then converted to an array) so I need to manipulate the vector.

To be clear, it takes a vector with these values:

`2 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 3 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 2`

And it makes this matrix:

`2 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 1 1
0 1 3 1 0
0 0 0 1 1
2 1 0 0 2`

But I want this matrix:

`2 0 0 0 2
1 1 1 0 1
1 0 3 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 1 2`

How do I manipulate my vector to make it like this?

Comment: Transpose the matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel as if you are looking for a [transposition of a matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose). There is relevant documentation [here.](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#t_st_members)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. And with Armadillo it's just a simple `.t()`